# HTML Agility Pack cannot find specific node

Tags: c#, html, .net, web, html-agility-pack

In my html I have node named `music-detail-header`.
My HTML:

```
<music-detail-header image-src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51du+vdj5WL.jpg" image-dimen="1:1" primary-text="Curated by Amazon’s Music Experts and Updated Fridays" secondary-text="The biggest songs in the world. Cover: Miley Cyrus." tertiary-text="50 SONGS  •  2 HOURS AND 43 MINUTES" image-kind="square" style="contain: layout; margin-top: 24px; display: block;" label="playlist" headline="All Hits" class="hydrated">
 <div slot="icons"><span class="_7Ge9Z_A8glJAPCM8OQ1xf">
  <music-button id="detailHeaderButton1" slot="icons" size="medium" icon-name="shuffle" title="Shuffle" aria-label="Shuffle" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" variant="solid" refinement="none" class="hydrated">Shuffle</music-button>
   </span>
   <span class="_7Ge9Z_A8glJAPCM8OQ1xf">
    <music-button id="detailHeaderButton2" slot="icons" size="small" icon-only="" icon-name="add" title="Add to My Music" aria-label="Add to My Music" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" variant="primary" refinement="none" class="hydrated"> 
     </music-button>
    </span>
   </div>
   <div slot="icons" class="_12yl6gY7_evjyhHEj91p3J">
   <span class="_7Ge9Z_A8glJAPCM8OQ1xf">
   <music-button id="detailHeaderButton3" slot="icons" size="small" icon-only="" icon-name="shareandroid" title="Share this playlist" aria-label="Share this playlist" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" variant="primary" refinement="none" class="hydrated"> 
   </music-button>
  </span>
 </div>
</music-detail-header>
```

But when I try to get it from page, like that:

```
public class HtmlScrapper
{
    public HtmlDocument? HtmlDocument { get; private set; }

    /// <param name = "URL"> URL of website to parse </param>
    public HtmlScrapper(string URL)
    {
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument = web.Load(URL);
    }

    public Playlist GetPlaylist()
    {
        var p = new Playlist();
        string Avatar = String.Empty;


        var node = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("//div/music-detail-header").FirstOrDefault();
        Avatar = node.GetAttributeValue("image-src", null);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(Avatar)))
        {
            p.Avatar = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

My `node` remains being `null`.
And then, of course, I get an exception here:

```
Avatar = node.GetAttributeValue("image-src", null);
```

I've already tried different methods of getting that element from document like:

`HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes`, `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes`, `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode` and others, but in all cases result is the same.
I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Without seeing the HTML code, it is difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: Generally speaking, when working with HAP, you need to be looking at the raw source as it comes from the server, not after it has been processed in your browser after running the javascript it has. HAP does not have that capability. That html snippet looks like it was generated, so you're not going to see it like that in your code. If you need to verify, inspect the contents of `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` and work from there.

Comment: With that said, your selector is ensuring that there's a parent `div` for that header, maybe you just want to do `//music-detail-header`?